# How to compute the derivative of composition $F(t) = f(A(4t, t), A(t, 2t))$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Let $f(x, y)$ denote a function of two variables whose partial derivatives – $f_x(x, y)$ and $f_y(x, y)$ – are considered to be “known” functions. Let $A(x, y)$ be another function whose partial derivatives, $A_x(x, y)$ and $A_y(x, y)$, are also considered to be known. Now consider the function $F(t) = f(A(4t, t), A(t, 2t))$. Compute, in terms of the known quantities, evaluated at appropriate arguments, the derivative $F'(t)$.

#### Progress

I know this question is very ambiguous, the professor seems give us questions like these a lot. I'm assuming you take the function  $F(t) = f(A(4t, t), A(t, 2t))$ and you have to use the chain rule on it, but I am confused as into how to take the derivative of the function and then answer it in terms the "known" variables.

Comment: He just wants you to write $F'$ as a function of the partials of $f$ and $A$. Does this formulation make it any more clear to you?

Comment: For example: if the question was to find the derivative of $A(4t,t)$ with respect to $t$, your answer would be $4A_x (4t,t) + A_y(4t,t)$. ("Known" derivatives in the answer).  Proceed in the same way: write down the derivative of $A(t,2t)$ and then put the things together.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the multivariate chain rule, like you said, but you will have to apply the rule multiple times to get the desired result:

The multivariate chain rule goes like this:

$\frac{df}{dt} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}\times\frac{d x_1}{dt}+\cdots+\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_n}\times\frac{d x_n}{dt}$

For your functions:

\begin{align}
F'(t)&=f_x(A(4t,t),A(t,2t))\times\frac{dA(4t,t)}{dt}+f_y(A(4t,t),A(t,2t))\times\frac{dA(t,2t)}{dt}\\&=f_x(A(4t,t),A(t,2t))\times(A_x(4t,t)\times4+A_y(4t,t))\\&+f_y(A(4t,t),A(t,2t))\times(A_x(t,2t)+A_y(t,2t)\times2)
\end{align}

When you are evaluating $\frac{dA(4t,t)}{dt}$ and $\frac{dA(t,2t)}{dt}$ that you got from the first chain rule, you have to apply the rule again.